# What is a common body composition in mammals?

Tags: physiology, mammals

[The Physiology Of The Racing Greyhound](http://www.bettingonthedogs.co.uk/GreyhoundPhysiology.aspx) states that most species have about a 40% muscle mass to body mass ratio. [Understanding Body Composition](http://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/underbodycomp.html) puts "optimal fitness" in humans at 16-25% body fat for women and 12-18% in men. These add up to pretty much anywhere from 50% to 65%, leaving 35-50% as more or less unaccounted for. In looking, I have been unable to readily locate any further breakdown, let alone any source that provides a full breakdown. At least [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_composition) is lacking in specifics in this regard.

**In adult, healthy mammals, what is a common body mass breakdown into muscle tissue, fat, bone, and internal organs, by percentage of total body mass?**

I am particularly interested in wild carnivores, but almost any mammalian species will do in a pinch. Specific examples and citations are appreciated.

Comment: If this question is a better fit on some other site, please feel free to migrate.

Comment: Think about the variety of body compositions in different mammals, even within a single species, heck across the life span of an individual; a bear coming out of hibernation will have a dramatically different composition compared to a bear going into hibernation.

Comment: @KevinCarolan That's why I wrote "adult, healthy mammals" and did my best to allow for answers discussing only specific species. However, if you feel that the answer is "there is no data available", then even though it pretty obviously isn't what I was hoping for when I wrote the question, that could certainly still be a valid answer to the question. (However, I still suspect that the figures quoted at the linked pages must come from *somewhere*.)